# Angularjs not updating variables

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope, angularjs-bindings

I want to display/update the calculation answer directly without the need of aditional buttons.
Or do i need a function and button to apply the changes?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

A_Number: <input type="number" step="1" ng-model="A_Number"><br> 

Display (A_Number): {{A_Number}}
<br>
square: {{square}} 
</div>
```

controller:

```
<script> 
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.square = $scope.A_Number * $scope.A_Number; 
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `square` as a method & use that method in interpolation directive, so that will evaluate on each digest.

**Markup**

```
square: {{square()}}
```

**Code**

```
$scope.square = function(){
    //made error free
    if(!isNaN($scope.A_Number))
      return $scope.A_Number * $scope.A_Number;
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: @Medera glad to hear that.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add watch on A_Number to achieve the same. JSFiddle for reference - 
https://jsfiddle.net/9a2xz61y/3/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.square = 0;
  $scope.$watch('A_Number', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    {
      if (!isNaN(newValue)) {
        $scope.square = $scope.A_Number * $scope.A_Number;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes agree - when object is complex and more fields to watch. I just mentioned as different approach to achieve the result.

Comment: still it shouldn't, also you should not use `true` option at the end of watcher, as here its no meaning for it